# Strange issue on foreach with listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, listbox

I'm trying to populate combobox from listbox elements.

this is code:

```
foreach(string elements in (Application.OpenForms[1] as Impostazioni).listBox1)
        {
            cbxValuta.Items.Add(elements);
        }
```

but I get this error from Visual Studio 2012:

> Error 1   foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' because 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox'
>   does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

I dont know how solve this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want iterate over ListBox elements you must use [Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx) property.

Try this:

```
foreach(string elements in (Application.OpenForms[1] as Impostazioni).listBox1.Items)
{
    cbxValuta.Items.Add(elements);
}
```

Error:

> But now I get this error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative
>   and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

First of all you must check if Application.OpenForms is not null and not empty.

So before foreach you must add following line of code:

If Application.OpenForms is list:

```
if(Application.OpenForms != null && Application.OpenForms.Count != 0)
```

If Application.OpenForms is array:

```
if(Application.OpenForms != null && Application.OpenForms.Length != 0)
```

Comment: done, thanks. But now I get this error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [`foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ttw7t8t6.aspx) in your code, your class should implement [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) or [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) interfaces.

Try with `.Items` property. Like;

```
(Application.OpenForms[1] as Impostazioni).listBox1.Items
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if `listBox1` has a `.Items` property that you can enumerate over.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the "Items" collection from listbox1 rather than using the entire listbox.

```
foreach(string elements in (Application.OpenForms[1] as Impostazioni).listBox1.Items)
    {
        cbxValuta.Items.Add(elements);
    }
```